# How to call a function placed in another directory in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, directory, call

I have a large project coded in `MATLAB`, with `15-18 scripts`. It is becoming very challenging to understand the whole code. I was thinking that if I can put some scripts in another folder, it will become very straightforward to understand and maintain the code. Is it possible to do that?

Consider the below directory structure:

[image]

How can I call a function from `main.m` that is placed in `func.m` in `Folder 1`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Manual solution**

Perform the following:

1. Right click on the folder which is on top of the hierarchy.
2. click on Add to path
3. Click on selected folders and subfolders

At this stage, your scripts will be able to identify any function or script which resides in one of the inner subfolders which you chose.
In addition you can call any script and function you would like by simply typing it's name in the command line.

**Code solution**

Instead of doing it manualy, it is also possible to add folders and subfolders into path by using the following code:

```
 addpath(genpath(<path to your directory>))
```

**Example**

The tree structure of the current Matlab path

[image]

You can add the functions and scripts from Folder 1 into path by either writing the following code:

```
addpath(genpath('Folder 1'))
```

Or by using 'Adding folders and subfolders' option from the menu:

[image]

After doing so, it is possible to call *func* straight from *main*

Answer (score 0):

As an additional answer a few years later, simply because I really like the way it works.
Especially in projects:

Simply sort all your functions and scripts into subfolders, which you name with a preceding "+".

[image]

The functions are then simply called with their name, but preceded by the name of the subfolder in which they are located:

```
[nameOfTheSubdirectory].[functionName]()
```

So according to my screenshot

```
subcatA.catAfunction()
```

The advantage is that you don't have to add any directories to the path and you can simply pass on the project in zipped form and it will still run on any system.

Just my way to keep my projects (and path) nice and clean ;)